# Winforms ListBox with DataSource bound to dotted path of nested object crashes when intermediate object of dotted path is null

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox

- The ListBox's `DataSource` is bound to `Detail.Tags`.
- When I select the first row, ListBox populates as expected.
- When I select the second row, the expected (and desired) result is that the ListBox simply **displays nothing**, because ItemB's `Detail` property is purposely null for demonstration purposes, so ItemB's `Detail.Tags` doesn't exist.
- Actual result is that program **crashes to desktop** with `System.ArgumentException: 'Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.'`

[image: screen capture]

Minimal reproducible example:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly IList<Item> _items;
        private BindingSource _bs = new BindingSource(){ DataSource = typeof(Item) };


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _items = GenerateSampleItems();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _items;
            listBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("DataSource", _bs, "Detail.Tags", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never));
        }
        

        private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
            {
                _bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            }
            else
            {
                _bs.DataSource = typeof(Item);
            }
        }


        private IList<Item> GenerateSampleItems()
        {
            return new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item()
                {
                    Name = "ItemA"
                    ,Detail = new Detail()
                    {
                         Expiration = new DateTime(2024,1,1)
                        ,Tags       = new BindingList<Tag>(new List<Tag>()
                                                          {
                                                              new Tag() 
                                                              { 
                                                                   TagName = "FirstT"
                                                                  ,TagValue = "FirstV"
                                                              }
                                                              ,new Tag() 
                                                              { 
                                                                   TagName = "SecondT"
                                                                  ,TagValue = "SecondV"
                                                              }
                                                          })
                    }
                }
                ,new Item()
                {
                    Name = "ItemB"
                    // Detail purposely omitted
                }
                ,new Item()
                {
                    Name = "ItemC"
                    // Detail purposely omitted
                }

            };
        }
    }


    class Item
    {
        public string Name              { get; set; }
        public Detail Detail            { get; set; }
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        public DateTime Expiration      { get; set; }
        public BindingList<Tag> Tags    { get; set; }      
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public string TagName           { get; set; }
        public string TagValue          { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: For comparison, giving ItemB and ItemC each their own empty Detail instance changes the error message, but it still crashes: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.'`

Comment: I tried working around the errors by filling out all objects so that no intermediate object on the dotted path would be null. Even this workaround does not really fix it, because I still get databinding crashes when multiselecting, or clicking in an empty gap such that no main row is selected. (In the real app, the left pane is a `BrightIdeasSoftware.FastDataListView` rather than a `DataGridView`.)

Comment: The docs page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 goes on at length in its "solar system" example about using dotted paths to bind to nested objects, but does not give a working example. That example seems similar to the Item/Detail/Tags hierarchy in my MRP (which clearly fails). I can adapt the accepted answer to my short term needs, but the question still remains on how (or if it's even possible) to correctly use the dotted paths approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by Creating a [`BindingSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) for each model:

1. Main `BindingSource` where its `DataSource` property is set to a list of `Item`. This one is the `DataGridView.DataSource`.
2. Second `BindingSource` to navigate the `Detail` data members of the main `BindingSource`.
3. Third one to navigate and display the `Tags` data members of the detail's `BindingSource`. This one is the `ListBox.DataSource`.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IList<Item> _items;
    private BindingSource _bsItems, _bsDetail, _bsTags;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        _items = GenerateSampleItems();
        _bsItems = new BindingSource(_items, null);
        _bsDetail = new BindingSource(_bsItems, "Detail");
        _bsTags = new BindingSource(_bsDetail, "Tags");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _bsItems;
        listBox1.DataSource = _bsTags;
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        _bsItems.Dispose();
        _bsDetail.Dispose();
        _bsTags.Dispose();
    }

    private IList<Item> GenerateSampleItems()
    {
        return new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item()
            {
                Name = "ItemA",
                Detail = new Detail
                {
                    Expiration = new DateTime(2024,1,1),
                    Tags = new BindingList<Tag>(new List<Tag>()
                    {
                        new Tag
                        {
                            TagName = "FirstT",
                            TagValue = "FirstV"
                        },
                        new Tag
                        {
                            TagName = "SecondT",
                            TagValue = "SecondV"
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            new Item()
            {
                Name = "ItemB"
                // Detail purposely omitted
            },
            new Item()
            {
                Name = "ItemC"
                // Detail purposely omitted
            }
        };
    }
}

// Elsewhere within the project's namespace
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }

    // Optional: Change, remove as needed...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {Name} - Detail: {Detail}";
    }
}

public class Detail
{
    public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
    public BindingList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    // Optional: Change, remove as needed...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var tags = $"[{string.Join(", ", Tags)}]";
        return $"Expiration: {Expiration} - Tags: {tags}";
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string TagValue { get; set; }

    // Optional: Change, remove as needed...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{TagName}: {TagValue}";
    }
}
```

That's all. No need to add `DataBindings` nor to handle the grid's `SelectionChanged` event as shown in your code snippet.

---

On the other hand, if you need to display the selected `Item.Detail.Tags`, then you need to [flatten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0) them in a list whenever the grid's selection changes and bind the result to the `ListBox`.

```cs
// +
using System.Linq;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingSource _bsItems;

    public Form1() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        _bsItems = new BindingSource(GenerateSampleItems(), null);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _bsItems;
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        _bsItems.Dispose();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = dataGridView1.SelectedCells
            .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            .Select(cell => cell.OwningRow).Distinct()
            .Where(row => (row.DataBoundItem as Item)?.Detail != null)
            .SelectMany(row => (row.DataBoundItem as Item).Detail.Tags)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This covers 90% of my needs, but this solution seems undiscoverable :(  The docs for `BindingSource.DataSource` and `BindingSource(Object, String)` constructor do not give any kind of hint that a BindingSource can refer to another BindingSource.

The other 10% of my needs are to correctly handle multiselect. When the user selects several items at once, the outermost BindingSource's `Current` points to the item they shift-clicked on, which is unsatisfying from a UX perspective. I'd rather have Current somehow point to a phantom proxy `Item` that represents "you are editing multiple now".